# NSight: file redirection in command line arguments

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, cuda, nsight

I can't manage to pass command line argument to my program when I launch it with "start CUDA debugging" in visual studio. (it works well with the visual studio debugger though). I tried setting my argument in visual studio parameters and in the Nsight parameter as explained in "[CUDA: Passing parameters to host compiler during Nsight session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13081401/cuda-passing-parameters-to-host-compiler-during-nsight-session)" but they get ignored.

My argument is a file representing my data. I set the parameter as :

```
< "..\\testData"
```

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 with Nsight 3.1.0

Thanks for your time !
Mickaël

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry to say that so far Nsight doesn't support parameter using "< file". It could not resolve file's content. But I have filed an enhancement request for developers. Hope we could support it in later versions. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! I don't know why but I couldn't find this limitation anywhere in the documentation. Anyway, I'm just using the file name as a parameter and I open it in the code.